# MS SQL Server 2005 and Node.JS

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server-2005, express

I'm new to web development and even more so to SQL.

I'm doing a small project using expressJS, and I'm wondering, is there some way to interact with a Database hosted in a MS SQL 2005 Server using expressJS?

I've had previous experience using mongoDB, but never SQL, and I'm kind of overwhelmed by all the different information in the internet.

Much appreciated.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/06/08/introducing-the-microsoft-driver-for-node-js-for-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately the blog is woefully out of date.

Comment: Given my experience in web development doing web apps, on Linux/Unix hosted servers and software, i would recommend a future reader of this post to take a look at Ruby on Rails for the backend that has a third-party library (gem) that has capabilities of querying 2005 (limited) ms sql server databases and officialy 2008 (full capabilities) and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the "official" drivers are Windows only. If you need a cross platform SQL Driver, checkout [tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious). There is some work going on to make [edge](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/) cross platform which would allow you to bridge .NET (or Mono) and Node.JS which would allow you to get much more performant [SQL access](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-script-t-sql-in-a-nodejs-application), but it is [not ready yet](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/3).